# Sql merging two text columns into single column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables t1 & t2.

```
table t1
 user_id  tags
   1      a,b,c
   2      b,c

table t2
 user_id  tags
   1      d,c
   2      c,d
```

I want to merge this into table t1. How can i do this.

```
 table t1
  user_id  tags
    1     a,b,c,d
    2     b,c,d
```

I am new in sql.

Comment: Please change your DB structure. You should **always** store only 1 value for everys column.

Comment: tags field is a text datatype

Comment: Don't store multiple tags in 1 column. It is called *normalization*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, although having more than one value in one field is not considered good practice and I couldn't recommend it.

```
SELECT t1.user_id, CONCAT(t1.tags, ', ', t2.tags) AS Tags
FROM table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

This won't show unique values but will come close to what you request, which is hampered by your data format.

**

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/97f92/9)

**

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.tags + ',' + t2.tags AS [Tags]
FROM t1 AS t1 INNER JOIN t2' at line 1

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to CONCAT.

Comment: This is the Exactly I asked for...
Thank you Very much for takingg time and doing the query for me.